# What are the chances the Chainlink oracle will respond to a non-existent request?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

The Chainlink [documentation](https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/subscription/examples/get-a-random-number#analyzing-the-contract) specifies that you should check that a request for a given `_requestId` exists before continuing.

[Chainlink Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLpGT.png)

I'm curious to further understand why this is, is it wrong to assume that the Oracle should never attempt to fulfil a request that has never been instantiated? For reference, I have reviewed the best practices section of the documentation and all attached code snippets do not follow this behaviour.

Thanks :)

Whilst developing the contract I am working on, I noticed this and wanted to gain a better understanding as to why the documentation validates a given request exists before fulfilling it.

Answer (score 0):

When the a randomness request is sent from VRFConsumer contract, a new requestId is generated:

```
        requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );
```

The contract has a struct `RequestStatus` containing them and stores the struct in a mapping `s_requests`.

After the oracle returns the random values to your contract, the mapping `s_requests` is supposed to be updated, and the `RequestStatus` of a specific request can be found by a specific `requestId`.

require statement in the fulfillment function is used to check if the requestId is indeed sent from the vrfConsumer contract.